# Using RewriteCond with WordPress's add_rewrite_rule()

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

## Background

I have changed a URL structure on a website that I manage, and need to set up redirects that change a query parameter, but keep the value.

After some research, I figured out a working rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^model=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(building-automation|lighting-controls)/display.php$ /?pagename=products/details/?SKU=%1 [QSA,L]
```

This will change this:

```
[DOMAIN]/building-automation/display.php?model=Product1
```

into this:

```
[DOMAIN]/?pagename=products/details&SKU=Product1
```

## Problem

I can't figure out how to get that rule to stay in the .htaccess file. I add it directly, and it gets removed when I update permalinks. So now I'm trying to add it using WordPress's `add_rewrite_rule()` function.

## Code so Far

The closest I've figured out is this:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '(building-automation|lighting-controls)/display.php?model=([^/]*)',
    '?pagename=products/details&SKU=$2',
    'top'
);
```

That creates this in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(building-automation|lighting-controls)/display.php?model=([^/]*) /?pagename=products/details&SKU=$2 [QSA,L]
```

And that RewriteRule doesn't work.

## Question

Is there a way to achieve the working RewriteRule using `add_rewrite_rule()`? Or, is there a different RewriteRule that I can use that doesn't require the RewriteCond, to achieve the change in HTTP query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrites are tricky, fortunately I just finished working with them a LOT so here's my best attempt to help you.  In WordPress you don't want to be calling php files directly like display.php.  That's your first issue in structure of your system, I'm not sure if that's a plugin or what but it's a bad idea and completely negates the reason for using WordPress in the first place.

Typically the URL would look something like /building-automation/details/Product1 and you would have a rewrite rule that made that point to /index.php?pagename=products/details&sku=product1

For that you need to have this inside WordPress so you would put it in your functions.php if using a child theme or create a very simple, one file plugin.

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^building-automation/details/([^/]+)/?$', 
    'index.php?pagename=products/details&sku=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

Then you'd need to add the rewrite tag so you can access the details query var:

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%sku%', '([^&]+)' );
```

Last you want to flush your rewrite rules either by visiting permalinks in your code with something like this.  You don't want to flush every page load though as it's expensive on your server:

```
if ( ! get_option( 'initial_rewrites_setup_flush' ) ) {
    flush_rewrite_rules( true );
    update_option( 'initial_rewrites_setup_flush', true );
}
```

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I don't have an option unfortunately. I'm redirecting **away** from the `display.php`, because that was the URL on the old pre-WP site. We are getting a lot of hits from people who have pages bookmarked though, and who are now getting 404 errors. Anyway, I figured out a workaround. I had to add my rule directly to the .htaccess file, because what I need can't be done with `add_rewrite_rules()`.

Comment: Yea, if you are directing from an old .php url then WordPress can't handle the rewrite for you.